# Minsk Airport VOA

Tags: visas, belarus, minsk

I will be in Eastern Europe next year and I'm looking at going through Belarus on my way home. When looking at the website here (http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/) I spotted two things of interest.

1. "Visa support documents. Entry visa applications for a purpose of business, private or for participation in sport or cultural activities for the period of up to 30 days of the citizens of Andorra, Argentina, ..., United States, and Uruguay *could* be considered by the consular officer without visa support documents, that confirm the purpose and conditions of the visit."

Does anyone know what is meant by "could" here (italics are my addition)? I am a national of one of the countries listed (well, actually, two). Is it advisable to travel to Belarus without such documents?

2. Differences in the cost of a visa for those countries with and without Belorussian consular representation.

How do I find out if my country has Belorussian representation.

I'd only be there 2 days (arriving by air from Kiev and leaving for Lithuania by bus) so would be eligible for a transit visa, which would cost the same as a short-stay visa applied for through the consulate (if it exists) - but requiring less pre-work.

My gut says just to apply at home and provide all documentation, but if anyone is familiar with travelling to Minsk/Belarus and thinks I'd be wasting my time, please speak up!

Comment: Applying in advance is highly appreciated, as consular services in airport are not quite adequate. And post your experience after the trip:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a visa on arrival at Minsk, but only with supporting documents sent in advance by a travel agency or hotel. Quote 1 refers to applications at embassies, where visas could be obtained for certain purposes without supporting documents. This is up to each embassy.

As for question 2, you can look up Belarusian embassies here http://belarusfacts.by/belembassy/index_eng.html